# Is there any method or tool other than nmap for the detection of an OS?

Tags: operating-systems, network-scanners, detection

I wanted to know if there was any other way to detect the OS of a network (other than nmap) since nmap doesn't detect most versions of Windows 10 at all and identifies them as a different OS altogether or as a different version of Windows.

How can I reliably detect Windows 10 on the network?

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of techniques. Some of them are:

- IP TTL values + TCP Window size
- DHCP requests
- MDNS
- ARP / NDP / SEND
- NetBIOS
- SSH / SSL / TLS

[Here](https://jonathansblog.co.uk/os-detection-techniques) is a great article about it. Don't forget to read [Nmap OS Detection](https://nmap.org/book/man-os-detection.html).

Comment: I have tried os detection using the nmap smb-os-discovery script seemed to work pretty good except for windows 10. Someone even raised it as an issue on their github about 2 years ago and the nmap accepted it as a bug about a year ago. I wrote this mainly to say thanks. So thanks.